# wrong numbering in table of contents in HTML

Tags: html, css, css-counter

I am trying to write Table of Contents using HTML in a file. The numbering that appears in my Table of Contents is flawed. How can I modify the following `CSS` and `HTML` so that the fourth bullet point in my `Output` is `4` instead of `3.4`?

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}

ol li {
  line-height: 30px;
}

ol ol li {
  line-height: 20px;
}

li {
  display: block;
}

li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".")" ";
  counter-increment: item;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <a href="#lorem_ipsum">lorem ipsum</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#set">Set</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#title">Title</a>
  </li>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <a href="#Class">Class</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#Something">Something</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#action">Action</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <li>
    <a href="#table_of_references">Table of References</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Output

```
1. Lorem Ipsum
2. Set
3. Title
    3.1. Class
    3.2. Something
    3.3. Action
3.4. Table of References
```

Comment: _"wrong numbering in table of contents in HTML"_ - well, write _invalid_ HTML, get unexpected results. `ol` can not be a child of `ol`.

Answer (score 5):

As the comment said (@Jon P): Your HTML is invalid. You can not have `ol` as a direct descendant of `ol` it needs to be wrapped in a `li`.

To nesting lists properly, just move the sub `ol` inside the 3rd li, check the example below:

> REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol
>
> [image]

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}

ol li {
  line-height: 30px;
}

ol ol li {
  line-height: 20px;
}

li {
  display: block;
}

li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".")" ";
  counter-increment: item;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <a href="#lorem_ipsum">lorem ipsum</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#set">Set</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#title">Title</a>
    <ol>
      <li>
        <a href="#Class">Class</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#Something">Something</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#action">Action</a>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#table_of_references">Table of References</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow @user7623610, If any answer helps you [vote it up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow), If the answer is what you looking for mark it as [Correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're closing your LI tag too early after Title - move it below the OL section, like this:

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <a href="#lorem_ipsum">lorem ipsum</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#set">Set</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#title">Title</a>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <a href="#Class">Class</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#Something">Something</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#action">Action</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#table_of_references">Table of References</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```